# Data structure supporting various kind of data type

Tags: database, data-structures

Suppose I have a dataset like the following:

Seq1 | Seq2 | Seq3 | disease | Age

====================================

A | T | G | Fever,Cough |   24

T | C | G | High Blood Pressure |   56

C | T | A | Diabetes, High Blood Pressure | 79

Which data structure should I choose that will support Alphabetical data {A/T/C/G}, set-valued data {Diabetes, High Blood Pressure}, and numeric data {age}?

If I have a coount query like: seq2 =T, Disease = 'High blood pressure', age>50 ==> the answer should be 2.

I was wondering what kind of data structure should I use to fit all types of data and above mentioned query efficiently? Or do I need to build 3 data structures and then intersect the results?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in an OOP language, consider creating a class that contains all the properties you need (Seq 1, Seq 2, Seq 3, list of symptoms, Age). You can then instantiate that class and put the resulting objects into various data structures (like a list).

Answer (score 0):

A class should be the right way to handle this structure, a simple implementation in C# would look like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DataStructure
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Creating Data Set
            var AllDataSet = new List<DataStructure>();
            AllDataSet.Add(
                new DataStructure(new char[] { 'A', 'T', 'G' }, new string[] { "Fever", "Cough" }, 24)           
            );

            AllDataSet.Add(
                new DataStructure(new char[] { 'T', 'C', 'G' }, new string[] { "High Blood Pressure" }, 56)
            );

            AllDataSet.Add(
                new DataStructure(new char[] { 'A', 'T', 'G' }, new string[] { "Diabetes", "High Blood Pressure" }, 79)
            );
        }
    }

    public class DataStructure
    {
        public char[] DNAChar;
        public string[] SetValuedData;
        public int Age;

        public DataStructure(char[] dnaChar, string[] setValuedData, int age)
        {
            DNAChar = dnaChar;
            SetValuedData = setValuedData;
            Age = age;
        }

        // Add other logic here
    }
}
```

Then you can add functionalities to implement your logic. Hope, this would help!